# Method delegation on field and cast in Bytebuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Using Bytebuddy assume the following:

```
class Service {
    protected Handler handler;
...
}

interface Handler {
   public void handle();
}

class ConcreteHandler implements Handler {
    public void handle() {
       ...
    }
    public void handle2() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Generally we call the handle() method of Handler, but in some cases we need to call handle2() of ConcreteHandler's class which is it in runtime. Now the question: is that possible using Bytebuddy? Probably yes, but how?

i tried that:

```
if (condition) {
    MethodCall methodCall = (MethodCall) 
        MethodCall.invoke(methodHandle2).onField("handler")
                        .withAssigner(Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC);
}
```

... but it fails with an IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke public void com.framework.ConcreteHandler.handle2(...) on protected com.framework.Handler com.framework.Service.handler

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Byte Buddy. I hopefully fixed the issue [in this commit](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/commit/ef005f93e28567a296a03e4a743aac9dbfabedab) which should resolve the issue in Byte Buddy 1.10.14. You can try the snapshot in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. What does that isInvokableOn() internally? Generally it sounds very suitable...

Comment: It checks if a method is invokable on a given type and a subtype method is not invokable on it's super type. Therefore, the check does not apply as it does not take the casting into consideration.

Comment: Understood. And within the commit you have weaken the check so that the casting takes place, right?

Comment: Yes. That's about it.

Comment: I can confirm that (a) this general thing was a problem in ByteBuddy and (b) 1.10.14-SNAPSHOT (built from source on 2020-07-16) fixed it. Thanks, @RafaelWinterhalter for the quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

If your field variable is a `Handler`, you cannot call `handle2()`, since Handler's don't know about the `handle2()` method.

In order to call the `handle2()` method (for a valid class), you'd need to cast the `handler` to a `ConcreteHandler` - a process known as "downcasting" as you're casting the instance to an object lower down in the object hierarchy. This only works when the `handler` instance is actually a `ConcreteHandler` rather than some other derivation of the `Handler`.

example:

```java
if (handler instanceof ConcreteHandler) {
   ConcreteHandler concreteHandler = (ConcreteHandler) handler;
   concreteHandler.handle2();
}
```

EDIT:
The one-off redirect I got working. I'm not entirely certain how you'd get it working as a permanent redirect from the docs but it would seem like redefine would work if you wanted to permanently redirect the method. There was also a change to the source necessary to make the classes ConcreteHandler, Handler, etc, public.

```java
 new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(ConcreteHandler.class)
                .method(named("handle")).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ConcreteHandler.class))
                .make()
                .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded()
                .newInstance()
                .handle2();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this question is in context of using ByteBuddy. This cast has to take place in Bytebuddy's description language....

Comment: ahh my bad! have you tried the delegation example here: https://www.baeldung.com/byte-buddy - I'm going to give it a try. I'll get back if I have any luck

Comment: I had a go at this and managed to redirect the call but only as a one off rather than permanently. I see the author has provided an answer. Its an interesting projec, not one I've come across before, so thanks for the question :)